# Yandex-касса, параметр return_url

Tags: яндекс-касса

Вот самый простой пример запроса на создание платежа:

```
    curl https://payment.yandex.net/api/v3/payments
-X POST
    -u <Идентификатор магазина>:<Секретный ключ>
    -H 'Idempotence-Key: <Ключ идемпотентности>'
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
    -d '{
        "amount": {
            "value": "9900.00",
            "currency": "RUB"
        },
        "confirmation": {
            "type": "redirect",
            "return_url": "https://example.com/url"
        },
        "description": "Слон большой, розовый"
    }'
```

В документации написано про return_url:
"URL, на который вернется пользователь после подтверждения или отмены платежа на веб-странице."
Вопросы:

1. С какой веб-страницы вернется пользователь? С веб-страницы, которая
   на Яндексе? Или с какой-то своей страницы, где я должен подтвердить
   намерение совершить платеж?
2. Если это страница на Яндексе, то почему параметр "return_url" в секции "confirmation"? Семантически непонятно.

Answer (score 0):

1. Имеется в виду страница Яндекса, вся обработка платежа происходит на его стороне, в том числе подтверждение кодом из смски
2. На этот вопрос вам может ответить только тот, кто писал апишку Яндекс-кассы

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/418063)

Comment: @Coder вы же про ответ на второй пункт? А как по-вашему можно ответить на вопрос об именовании параметров запроса к API?

Comment: высказывание не проясняет ситуацию, и не может полагаться ответом, имхо.

Answer (score 0):

Это ссылка "Вернуться в магазин" на сайте приёма платежа яндекса,
на который вернется пользователь после `подтверждения или отмены` платежа